# Schlessinger criterion and finiteness of tangent space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, simplicial-stuff, deformation-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

Schlessinger's criterion allows us to study whether or not a functor $\mathcal{F}:C_{\Lambda}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ from the category of local Artin $\Lambda$-algebras to sets is representable. One of the necessary consditions is that the tangent space $t_{\mathcal{F}}:=\mathcal{F}(k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2))$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, where $k$ is the residue field of $\Lambda$.

A generalization or maybe an analogue of this is the derived Schlessinger criterion, due to mainly Lurie if I'm not mistaken (see https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/ashwin.iyengar/lntsg2019/G8.pdf Thm 3.5). If I'm not mistaken, in this case we allow the tangent space to be possibly infinite, by which I mean that $H_0(\mathfrak{t}\mathcal{F})$ can be infinite dimensional.

So if I start with a "nice" functor $\mathcal{F}:C_{\Lambda}\rightarrow \text{Set}$, whose tangent space is not finite dimensional, can the induced functor
$$s\mathcal{F}:sC_{\Lambda}\rightarrow s\text{Set}$$
be pro-representable? In a more optimistic sense, if $\mathcal{F}$ does satisfy every condition of Schlessinger's criterion except the finiteness of $t_{\mathcal{F}}$, is $s\mathcal{F}$ pro-representable?

Comment: A nice functor on $C$ won't induce a nice functor on $sC$ - that's extra structure. Infinite-dimensional tangent spaces were successfully handled by Grothendieck before Schlessinger - see the FGA paper cited by Schlessinger. The derived Schlessinger criterion is really just Brown representability as formulated by Heller or Jardine.

Comment: I should perhaps add that http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0344 appeared 3 years before Lurie's ICM address.

Comment: Dear Jon, I suppose I owe you an apology for missing your paper. I'm not certain to which Grothendieck paper you refer, could you maybe give me a more precise reference? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Technique de descent et theoremes de d'existence en geometrie algebrique, 11, Seminaire Bourbaki, Expose 195, 1959/1960